# Not able to find Index of Dropdownlist in c# .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu, listbox

hi i have a gridview in which i have created a panel,that panel has a dropdownlist of the name of states which on selection should update the value of list box right below with name of Cities in that state.
my problem is that i'm unable to call the selectedIndexchange function of dropdownlist(on disabling viewstatemode, the function gets called but selectedindex value is null)

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvCountry1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataKeyNames="ID"  OnRowDataBound="gvCountry1_OnRowDataBound" 
    onselectedindexchanged="gvCountry1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
        <img alt = "" style="cursor: pointer" src="images/plus.png" />
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlStates" runat="server" style="display:none">
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStates1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlStates1_OnSelectedIndexChanged" >
        <asp:ListItem Text="Select State" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList><br />
        <asp:ListBox ID="lbCity" runat="server"></asp:ListBox>
        </asp:Panel>
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Back End Code:-

```
protected void gvCountry1_OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            string countryid = gvCountry1.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
            ddlStates1 = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlStates1");
            lbCity=(ListBox)e.Row.FindControl("lbCity");
            SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter();
            String conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection"].ConnectionString;
            con.ConnectionString = conString;
            String conCmd = "sp_SelectStateList";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = conCmd;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@countryid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = countryid;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            adp.SelectCommand = cmd;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adp.Fill(ds);
            con.Open();
            ddlStates1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            ddlStates1.DataTextField = "State";
            ddlStates1.DataValueField = "ID";
            ddlStates1.DataBind();
            con.Close();
            ddlStates1.SelectedIndexChanged += ddlStates1_OnSelectedIndexChanged;
            conCmd = "sp_SelectCityList";
            cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = conCmd;
            string stateid = ddlStates1.SelectedValue;
            Session["stateid"] = stateid;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stateid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = stateid;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            adp.SelectCommand = cmd;
            ds = new DataSet();
            adp.Fill(ds);
            con.Open();
            lbCity.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            lbCity.DataTextField = "City";
            lbCity.DataValueField = "ID";
            lbCity.DataBind();
            con.Close();
            ddlStates1.ViewStateMode = ViewStateMode.Disabled;

        }
    }

    protected void ddlStates1_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string stateid = ddlStates1.SelectedValue;
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter();
        String conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection"].ConnectionString;
        con.ConnectionString = conString;
        String conCmd = "sp_SelectCityList";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = conCmd;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stateid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = stateid;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        adp.SelectCommand = cmd;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adp.Fill(ds);
        con.Open();
        lbCity.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        lbCity.DataTextField = "City";
        lbCity.DataValueField = "ID";
        lbCity.DataBind();
        con.Close();
        ddlStates1.ViewStateMode = ViewStateMode.Enabled;
    }
```

i am new to c# .net kindly help me where i'm wrong

Comment: Does disabling ViewStateMode mean the user can't select an option? If so, that is why selected index is null.

Comment: I can change Option from the dropdownlist but when i try to find the selectedvalue or selected index it shows error of null reference pointer

Comment: Try using SelectedValue

Comment: Are you databinding your drop-down list every trip back to the server, or just on a postback? If you're doing it every time, it could be that the server doesn't think anything has been selected, therefore the event won't fire. Check to ensure it's not posting back when you change the value.

Comment: and how do i implement that?